# From Kernel Density to a polygon that covers 80 % of points

Tags: polygon-creation, kernel-density

I have a set of occurrences as points in a district. I used Kernel Density tool, to show the areas of various densities. I also want to create one polygon that covers X % of points. I've tried the Locate Region tool but dont feel like this is quite the right method, as its not clear to me how it works and seems to be more for finding locations at set distances to other 'suitable' locations. I'm working in ArcGIS 10.1.5.

Comment: I do not know of a one-click solution in ArcMap, however, if you have some basic skills in R it can be done quite simply using the adehabitatHR package.

Comment: Percent volume contours can also be derived from a raster object, without the coercion overhead to estUDm and then back to a SpatialPixelsDataFrame, using the spatialEco::raster.vol function.